# Refactoring navbar with an active class in a partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, refactoring

This is what I have and I want to include it in a partial so that I am not duplicating it in 4 places. The problem is the active class which should change based on the page the user is on. How can I go about this? Or am I better off just repeating the code in 4 templates?

```
<div class="navbox">
  <ul class="nav">
    <a href="#" class="active"> Account</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li> Profile</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li> Photos</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li> Security</li></a>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass in an `active` local when rendering:

```
render :partial => 'navbox', :locals => { :active => 'Account' }
```

Then have this as your partial:

```
<div class="navbox">
  <ul class="nav">
    <a href="#"<% if active == 'Account' %> class="active"<% end %>> Account</li></a>
    <a href="#"<% if active == 'Profile' %> class="active"<% end %>><li> Profile</li></a>
    <a href="#"<% if active == 'Photos' %> class="active"<% end %>><li> Photos</li></a>
    <a href="#"<% if active == 'Security' %> class="active"<% end %>><li> Security</li></a>
  </ul>
</div>
```

There's various ways this could be cleaned-up (`link_to`, helper methods, etc.), which is left as an exercise. You could also potentially avoid needing to pass in a local if you can deduce whether something is “active” from the request URL.

Also have a look at [`link_to_unless_current`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to_unless_current) & [`link_to_unless`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to_unless) if you don't want to link at all instead of adding a class to the link.

Comment: Im afraid the locals is not working right. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I do think in your code it should be <% if :active as opposed to <% if active but that isn't solving the problem. When you say render navbox do you mean rendering a partial _navbox.html/erb? I have a partial called _settop.html.erb in a shared folder and I am using render 'shared/settop', :locals => { :active => 'Account' }. But it does not work. There are no error messages. Its just that the active class isn't being applied at all.

Comment: Nope, definitely `if active`, `if :active` will always be true. I mean render whatever partial you have that HTML in. You should verify that `active` has a value in your partial by doing `<% raise active.inspect %>` or similar.

Comment: I get undefined local variable when i say if active

Comment: @pratski Try my updated answer, think I got the API for `render` wrong.

Comment: Worked like a charm!! I spent hours with this. But getting it right is more gratifying than the frustration caused trying!!!! Thank you so much!!!!!!

Comment: No problem. Also, btw, just realized that you have the `<a>`s and `<li>`s flipped. The only allowable immediate descendant of a `<ul>` (or `<ol>`) is an `<li>`.

Answer (score 2):

Look for the active_link_to gem https://github.com/twg/active_link_to
It is the easiest way

Comment: Definitely easy. But not the best approach from a learning perspective for something that is relatively basic. But does get you to the same place without much thinking or effort. Thanks for the answer. Now that I know how it works maybe I'll use the gem next time!

Answer (score 2):

You can try to crete helper like this:

```
{'Account' => account_path, 'Profile' => profile_path...etc}.each do |name, path|
  content_tag :li do
    link_to name, path, class: (current_page?(path) 'active' : 'regular')
  end
end
```

Also take a look at method `link_to_unless_current` http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to_unless_current

Comment: one minor mod -- it should be `link_to name, path, class: (current_page?(path) ? 'active' : 'regular')` (needs the question mark to complete the ternary). But this is the an excellent answer.